# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate is not updating database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, findoneandupdate

I have a database that has a structure to this. I've updated the values clearly, but the idea remains. I'm trying to essentially find the refresh token and update it with a new token. Here is the database structure sample

```
{
  "_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "username": "abcd@yahoo.com",
  "refreshTokens": [
    {
      "refreshToken": "token_example_1",
      "_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
  ],
  "salt": "salted_stuff",
  "hash": "hashed_stuff",
  "__v": 1
}
```

Here is my schema structure

```
const session = new Schema({
  refreshToken: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
  },
});

const userSchema = new Schema({
  password: String,
  refreshTokens: [session],
});

userSchema.set('toJSON', {
  transform: function (doc, ret, options) {
    delete ret.refreshToken;
    return ret;
  },
});
```

Now, what I'm trying to do to update it is

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: userId, refreshTokens: { $elemMatch: { refreshToken: refreshToken } } },
        { $set: { 'refreshTokens.$.refreshToken': newRefreshToken } }
      );
```

newRefreshToken is built from another function and userId is a variable based off another function of retrieving that internally. Both of those are working as I've consoled logged them and can see they are correct.

When I check the database, the refreshToken doesn't change after running the query.

Am I doing something wrong here? The original user creation and everything works fine so I know the connection is there and it's not returning any errors. Even this update isn't returning errors. It's just not updating the data.

I have scoured multiple other questions and forums. I tried mongoplayground and it seemed to work, so not sure why it's not actually working.

I've also tried

```
User.updateOne(
        { _id: userId, refreshTokens: { $elemMatch: { refreshToken: refreshToken } } },
        { $set: { 'refreshTokens.$.refreshToken': newRefreshToken } }
      );
```

and

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: userId, 'refreshTokens.refreshToken': refreshToken } } },
        { $set: { 'refreshTokens.$.refreshToken': newRefreshToken } }
      );
```

No success so far. And if I try to do a

```
.then((user) => {user.save()})
```

I get an error saying that is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else that runs across this with the same issue...

I ended up having to set the .post as an async function and then use .await plus .exec() for the findOneAndUpdate function like below

```
router.post('/refreshToken', async (req, res, next) => {
...
        await User.findOneAndUpdate(
          {
            _id: userId,
            refreshTokens: {
              $elemMatch: { refreshToken: refreshToken },
            },
          },
          {
            $set: { 'refreshTokens.$.refreshToken': newRefreshToken },
          }
        )
          .exec()
...
}
```

This forced the database to update before creating the new cookie and storing the new token.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I notice that you have 2 extra brackets in your original code. The fix is below:

```
{
    "_id": "64480569a2c60bc65d10b377",
    "username": "markapiland@yahoo.com",
    "refreshTokens": [
      {
        "refreshToken": "token_example_1",
        "_id": "64480569a2c60bc65d10b37a"
        }
    ],
    "salt": "salted_stuff",
    "hash": "hashed_stuff",
    "__v": 1
  }
```

Maybe instead of

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: userId, refreshTokens: { $elemMatch: { refreshToken: refreshToken } } },
        { $set: { 'refreshTokens.$.refreshToken': newRefreshToken } }
      );
```

You can try:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: userId, "refreshTokens.refreshToken": refreshToken  },
        { $set: { 'refreshTokens.$.refreshToken': newRefreshToken } }
      );
```

Comment: Yep, I'll edit the original code. That was an error from me trying to refactor the way mongoDB likes to show it. I'll give your suggestion a shot and see what happens!

Comment: Unfortunately, it still didn't work. I appreciate the response, though.